# Gradle Build Errors in Android Studio

Tags: android

It's my first time using Android Studio, or developing an Android app in general, so I'm sorry if it's an obvious error.

When I try to build my app I get errors, as seen below.

```
Information:Gradle tasks [:app:generateDebugSources, :app:generateDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:mockableAndroidJar, :app:compileDebugAndroidTestSources, :app:compileDebugUnitTestSources, :app:compileDebugSources]
H:\Stage_3\CEG3799_Individual_Research_Project\App\CEG3799\app\build\intermediates\manifests\full\debug\AndroidManifest.xml
    Error:(36) error: unknown element <activity> found.
    Error:(36) unknown element <activity> found.
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:java.util.concurrent.ExecutionException: com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:com.android.tools.aapt2.Aapt2Exception: AAPT2 error: check logs for details
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugResources'.
Failed to execute aapt
> Information:BUILD FAILED in 4s
> Information:6 errors
> Information:0 warnings
> Information:See complete output in console
```

The debug file it is referring to is https://pastebin.com/Yyc1wGDL. The main AndroidManifest.xml file is https://pastebin.com/kj978xd4. If I try and move my `<activity>` to inside my `<application>`, I get the following error instead.

```
Error:Execution failed for task ':app:processDebugManifest'.
> Manifest merger failed with multiple errors, see logs
```

This is the console / logs that I can find https://pastebin.com/pT1m0GLZ.
The build.gradle is at https://pastebin.com/6r5ys8Fi

Can anyone help advise me how to get this working? Thank you in advance

Comment: can you also paste your build.gradle file.

Comment: I've just edited to include it. https://pastebin.com/6r5ys8Fi

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you move `<activity>` inside `<application>` you'll have two `<activity>` tags with the same `android:name="uk.ac.ncl.b5027438.CEG3799.MainActivity"`. delete one of these tags

Comment: You're correct. It's because I had two `<activity>` tags. It seems to be sorted now, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Move the

```
<activity
       android:name="uk.ac.ncl.b5027438.CEG3799.MainActivity"
       android:configChanges="screenSize|orientation" />
```

inside the `<application>` node

Comment: I thought that I would have to do that, but when I did that I got manifest merger errors as I mentioned in the question.

Comment: In your question I only see `unknown element <activity> found`. You should add more details. Also pay attention to avoid duplicate Activity in the Manifest.

Comment: Thanks for the help, it appears to have been the duplicated `<activity>` tags, as @y.allam advised me about too.